# PermitAll gives unauthorized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot application and I want to permit all my requests to `/pub` but it returns *unauthorized 401*. Who knows the cause?

This is my code:

```kotlin
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
class ResourceServerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun apiFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain? {

        http
            .apply(AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer())
                .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/pub").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();


        return http.build()
    }
}
```

**Update 1**: so i added `.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()` and it worked but i discovered another problem , if the public endpoint has an authorization header it will give me 401 even when it did not have it it worked , for example if i just get request http://localhost:8080/pub it will give me 200 but if i put an authorization header with a bearer token it will give me 401 , very strange xD

Comment: yes i got it, anyway the token are present in headers when you try to invoke permit all endpoint ?

Comment: no , i do not at all use the token neither authorization header , i want /pub to be a public endpoint

Comment: Could you share also how `/pub` controller looks like

Comment: Well  permitAll means you are either authenticated successfully or not. If you provide an authorization header but it is not one that allows authentication then you get your 401.